# Primefaces commandButton in dataTable - cannot set property in bean or cannot update the table

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I start with examples:

`Example 1`

```
<p:dataTable>
...
<p:column headerText="Actions" style="text-align:center; width:100px;">
    <p:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete}"
        update="data">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.key}" value="#{item.key}" />            
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

`Example 2`

```
<p:dataTable>
...
<p:column headerText="Actions" style="text-align:center; width:100px;">
    <p:commandLink value="Delete" actionListener="#{bean.delete}"
        update="data">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.key}" value="#{item.key}" />            
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

In the first case (command link with `action`), property `bean.key` is set correctly but the table is not rendered again after the item is deleted.

In the second case (command link with `actionListener`), property is not set and I get `NullPointerException`. But I have another command link with `actionListener` outside the table and it works fine and updates the table.

How can I make the first case to render the table after the item is deleted or somehow solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try update="@form" ? This would render more than table but worth trying.

Comment: Neither `@form` or `@all` helped. But I added a confirm dialog which triggers the method and renders the table and it's working.

Comment: You can also try h:commandLink with f:ajax, to exclude possibility it's primefaces related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add attribute `prependId=false` to the form tag which wraps component with `id="update"`

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

advice: add attribute `process="@this"` to your `<p:commandLink value="Delete" ...>`
in this case you submit just this one component instead of all components in the form

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance that you have two `forms`? and the `p:commandLink` is in the first `form` and the render component (the one with the `id="data"`) is in the second `form`?.
Then you should assign an `id` to the second `form` and your commandLink should be like `<p:commandLink... update=":secondformid:data">`.
If you are using PrimeFaces 3.0 you can read more in the PrimeFaces User's Guide, chapter 4, section 4.1.2 Partial Rendering and Processing->Using IDs.
http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html
Sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

A tip (or trick):
Instead of:

```
<p:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete}" update="data">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.key}" value="#{item.key}" />            
</p:commandLink>
```

You could use:

```
<p:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete}" actionListener="#{bean.setKey(item.key)}" update="data" />
```

This way you use the actionListener to explicitly call the setter and set the property.

Comment: Can you ensure that the actionListener method is called before the action method? I don't want to end up with NPE.

Comment: The actionListener should be executed first. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener